# aem curl with filter option is not working

Tags: curl, aem

Im using cURL in windows. Add filters is not working for me. Please help me to resolve the issue

```
# create package
curl -u admin:admin -X POST <url>?cmd=create -d packageName=testpackage -d groupName=my_packages

# add filters

curl -u admin:admin -X POST http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/update.jsp -F path=/etc/packages/my_packages/testpackage.zip -F packageName=testpackage -F groupName=my_packages -F 'filter=[{'root':'/content/dam/pdf/sample/pdffiles'}]' -F '_charset_=UTF-8'

# build package

curl -u admin:admin -X POST http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service/.json/etc/packages/my_packages/testpackage.zip?cmd=build
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows the single quote doesn't work. You have to put the parameter inside the double quote.

```
"filter=[{'root':'/content/dam/pdf/sample/pdffiles'}]" -F "charset=UTF-8"
^                                                    ^    ^             ^
```

To debug yourself you can use `-v` switch of curl.